# Hard limit on MaxResults for listing events in Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to list the events in a calendar using the google calendar API v3 (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). I'd rather not deal with paging, is there a hard limit on the MaxResults property? Can I make it 365 at least?

Answer (score 0):

just testing on my own, you can set MaxResults to at the very least 365 and it will work

Comment: be careful that maxResults also includes any deleted events even if they aren't shown or returned to you! I have to raise maxResults to 9999 just so i dont get page after page of empty results since i create and delete a lot of events